# Transparent CommandBar/AppBar in Windows Universal Application (UWP)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Is there any supported way for making a CommandBar or AppBar semi-transparent in a Windows Universal Application (UWP)?

Not even editing the control template of the CommandBar appears to have any effect.

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the opacity? I do this a lot in winforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color with an argb value, for example:
**#260000FF**

15% opacity
0 red
0 green
255 blue

The option is in **Brush** -> **Background**
[image]

**100% opacity**
[image]

**15% opacity**
[image]
I hope this can help you

Comment: You are able to see an Image shown on the page THROUGH the appbar?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold yes, I have tested it with an image and I can see it

Comment: The only way I can make this work if I use an appbar without assinging it to Page.BottomAppBar or Page.TopAppBar.

Comment: I changed the CompositeMode of CommandBar to SourceOver and when you click in more (...), the image is behind the appbar

Comment: That works even without touching the CompositeMode but unfortunately only for the small part of the appbar that extends when clicking ...